# sbt dependency resolver with basic auth

Tags: sbt, ivy, basic-authentication

I have nginx for my maven repository with basic authorization.

My build.sbt has:

```
credentials += Credentials("maven repository", "rep.com", "sbt", "password")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "maven repository" at "http://rep.com:8080/"
)
```

but, sbt can't found module because sbt doesn't use basic authorization.

My nginx logs looks like:

```
012/07/22 20:02:21 [error] 3338#0: *14 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 8.32.39.29, server: rep.com, request: "HEAD /some/cool_2.9.1/0.1-SNAPSHOT/cool_2.9.1-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom HTTP/1.1", host: "rep.com:8080"
```

I don't wanna to publish artifacts through nginx. Basic auth need only for restricted access to artifacts.

How I can restrict access and working with repository in sbt?

Comment: I've found [this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.simple-build-tool/4055) that may help you, but IMO, it doesn't contain enough details to reproduce solution, so it would be wonderfull, if somebody will dig into it and provide detailed answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what details are missing?  The reply from Harald in that thread seems straightforward to me: make sure the realm matches.  The reply to that from sebastien suggests using the system propery `javax.net.debug=all` to find out the authentication realm.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about adding the following to your ~/.ivy2/.credentials:

```
realm=maven repository
host=rep.com:8080
user=username
password=password
```

and then use `Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")`

you need to ensure that your realm is configured correctly: `curl http://rep.com:8080 -vv 2>&1 | egrep "realm|host"` (I might be mistaken, but 'host' may have to match the host header, i.e. rep.com:8080, not just rep.com).

hth

Comment: You don't need to put in the .credentials file. I twas the host not lining up that was the issue.

Comment: This approach has now been added to the SBT docs. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html

Comment: The grep expression is not using the expected case use :
curl http://rep.com:8080 -vv 2>&1 | egrep -i "realm|host"
 --> Result is expected to have 2 lines like this : 

--> Host: nexus.eu
--> WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an SVN repository which uses basic AUTH. 
This post and the one alluded to above got me the answer which I summarise below.

As alluded to above its all about getting the realm correct:

In build.sbt i set my resolver as follows:

```
resolvers += {
Credentials.add("<realm>", "<svnhost?", "<username>", "<password>")
Resolver.url("name", url("http://<svnhost>/<path>/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns) 
}
```

To find the realm value which is the first param for Credentials.add, i did

```
curl http://<svn host> -v
```

and used the Basic Realm value reported in the WWW-Authenticate header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="<realm>"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it works, but just try adding the basic auth in the URL:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "maven repository" at "http://username:password@rep.com:8080/"
)
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for me with SBT 1.2.8 or SBT 1.3.9.